# Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey: Parameter Invalid

Tags: c#, registrykey

Is it possible to create directly under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE aside from HARDWARE, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, etc.. using C#? I've tried the following code, but I'm getting an error:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("TESTFOLDER", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, RegistryOptions.None);
```

The error states:

> Parameter invalid

I've already tried executing my application as an administrator.

Comment: I can't create such a key using regedt running as administrator or local system so that would tend to point to no. Best just use the areas of the registry which are *designated* for the purpose for which you wanted to use it.

Comment: hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sorry for not getting back on you ASAP. Still finding some explanation as to why this is not possible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry contains a mixture of elements. Many parts of the registry have files which store them when the operating system isn't running - these are described under the help for [Registry Hives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives)

There you'll see that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` doesn't have a hive file. Several keys under it, such as `Sam` and `Software` have individual hive files. Others, such as `Hardware` do not. This is logical - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware` is recreated anew each time the OS boots.

In turn, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is also created anew each time the OS boots and then attaches subkeys, some coming from Hive files, some having been created.

You cannot create a new subkey under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` because the OS doesn't have anywhere to store it (it's not backed by a Hive itself) nor have any knowledge to recreate it the next time it boots.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to late. I asked other developers and I think this is the best answer there is. Thanks!